# iPhone: What are the different kinds of encodings that dataUsingEncoding supports?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Can anyone point me to any article or document that lists all the encoding types that "dataUsingEncoding" in iPhone supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) availableStringEncodings method will return a list of available encodings - the current (as of iOS 4.2) options being:

- NSASCIIStringEncoding
- NSUnicodeStringEncoding
- NSISOLatin1StringEncoding
- NSISOLatin2StringEncoding
- NSSymbolStringEncoding

Comment: Those are some commonly used ones (though `NSUTF8StringEncoding` is missing from that list and is probably the most common one nowadays), but a lot more are available, see the [Constants section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE) in the `NSString` docs.

Answer (score 2):

```
//This can print all of encoding that iPhone supports
NSMutableArray *arrayOfEncodings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

const NSStringEncoding *encodings = [NSString availableStringEncodings];
while (*encodings != 0){
    [arrayOfEncodings addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLong:*encodings]];
    encodings++;
}

for (int i=0; i<arrayOfEncodings.count; i++) {
    NSStringEncoding aNSStringEncoding = [[arrayOfEncodings objectAtIndex:i] unsignedLongValue];
    CFStringEncoding aCFStringEncoding = CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(aNSStringEncoding);
    CFStringRef encodingNameInCFString = CFStringGetNameOfEncoding(aCFStringEncoding);
    NSString * encodingName = (NSString*)encodingNameInCFString;
    NSLog(@"%@", encodingName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[NSString availableStringEncodings]